# How to check whether a variable contains spaces in a Makefile ?

Tags: makefile

I want to know whether the variable CHAPTER contains spaces. I tried to use findstring without success :

```
CHAPTER=default
new:
ifeq (" ",$(findstring " ",$(CHAPTER)))
    $(error Variable contains space)
else
    echo "variable ok"
endif
```

This code says "variable ok" whereas I would expect the opposite.

What am I doing wrong ?

How should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just test whether the variable value is a single word or not using [`words` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
ifneq (1,$(words [$(CHAPTER)]))
# Things are bad...
endif
```

Notice the square braces, which help to detect leading/trailing whitespaces as well.

### UPD.

Another option is to define a variable with a single space in its value and search the target variable for occurrences.

```
space :=
space +=

ifneq (,$(findstring,$(space),$(CHAPTER)))
# Things are bad...
endif
```